# How to launch nodelet? (RTABmap)

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I came up across remote mapping and RTABmap provides this launch file:

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find freenect_launch)/launch/freenect.launch">
     <arg name="depth_registration" value="True" />
  </include>

  <arg name="rate"  default="5"/>
  <arg name="approx_sync" default="true" /> <!-- true for freenect driver -->

  <!-- Use same nodelet used by Freenect/OpenNI -->
  <group ns="camera">
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="data_throttle" args="load rtabmap_ros/rgbd_sync camera_nodelet_manager" output="screen">
      <param name="compressed_rate"  type="double" value="$(arg rate)"/>
      <param name="approx_sync"      type="bool"   value="$(arg approx_sync)"/>

      <remap from="rgb/image"       to="rgb/image_rect_color"/>
      <remap from="depth/image"     to="depth_registered/image_raw"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="rgb/camera_info"/>

      <remap from="rgbd_image"      to="rgbd_image"/>
    </node>
  </group>      
</launch>
```

What is the camera_nodelet_manager and how can I supply it? For example, if I use ZED camera they supply with the camera_manager:
https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper/blob/master/zed_wrapper/launch/zed_camera_nodelet.launch

But how exactly can I use it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320061/how-to-launch-nodelet?-(rtabmap)/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-04-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-04-03**:
See this page: https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper/tree/master/examples/zed_nodelet_example, showing how they start the nodelet manager. If you use the zed launch version without nodelet, launch rgbd_sync as a stanaldone nodelet like this :

```
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="data_throttle" args="standalone rtabmap_ros/rgbd_sync" output="screen">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can see [#q304083](https://answers.ros.org/question/304071/how-to-load-two-seperate-nodelets-in-the-nodelet-manager/#304083) for an example.

This launch file provides the nodelet manager when including `freenect.launch`. If you look at this file ([source code](https://github.com/ros-drivers/freenect_stack/blob/master/freenect_launch/launch/freenect.launch)) you will find this :

```
<include file="$(find rgbd_launch)/launch/includes/manager.launch.xml">
      <arg name="name"                value="$(arg manager)" />
      <arg name="debug"               value="$(arg debug)" />
      <arg name="num_worker_threads"  value="$(arg num_worker_threads)" />
</include>
```

This other launch file load the nodelet manager for you. In the link you gave, the launch file doesn't load any nodelet manager but expect one : `zed_nodelet_manager`. So if you want to use this launch file, all you have to do is load a manager before like this :

```
rosrun nodelet nodelet manager __name:=zed_nodelet_manager
```

Or by adding this line at the beginning of the launch file you linked :

```
< node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="$(arg nodelet_manager_name)" args="manager"/>
```

You need a nodelet manager because nodelets are like plugins, they are loaded at runtime by an executable, this executable being your nodelet manager. This [link](https://medium.com/@waleedmansoor/understanding-ros-nodelets-c43a11c8169e) might help you understand the concept of nodelets.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0